# +[RLMRealm setDefaultRealmPath:] not found when upgrading from old version of Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm upgrading my Objective-C project to a newer version of Realm but am having some problems. The code below works with the version of Realm I was using, but not with the new version:

```
+ (void)setupRealm {
    NSURL *realmURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP_ID];
    NSString *realmPath = [realmURL.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SingPost.realm"];

    [RLMRealm setDefaultRealmPath:realmPath];
    NSLog(@"Default Realm Path : %@",[RLMRealm defaultRealmPath]);
}
```

The error is:

[image: error]

How can I set the default Realm path in new versions of Realm?

Comment: I think they removed that method, try create a `RLMRealmConfiguration` with that path and apply to the `RLMRealm`

Comment: hi can give some detail. I did not see any .path method in RLMRealmConfiguration

Comment: It have a method called `setPath:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+[RLMRealm defaultRealmPath]` / `+[RLMRealm setDefaultRealmPath:]` were deprecated in [Realm v0.95.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v0.95.0), released nearly a year ago, and have since been removed. They were replaced by the `fileURL` property on the `RLMRealmConfiguration` class.

```
+ (void)setupRealm {
    NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP_ID];
    NSURL *realmURL = [containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SingPost.realm"];

    RLMRealmConfiguration *configuration = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    configuration.fileURL = realmURL;
    [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:configuration];

    NSLog(@"Default Realm location: %@", realmURL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It work for the setup. but I have new error with this - (void)didDeactivate {
    [super didDeactivate];
    [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] removeNotification:self.notificationToken];
}

Comment: Error is /Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/App/Version3/SingPost/SingPost WatchKit Extension/ParcelController.m:37:30: No visible @interface for 'RLMRealm' declares the selector 'removeNotification:'

Comment: Please read over [Realm's change log](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v1.0.2/CHANGELOG.md), paying special attention to the entries marked as API breaking changes, to learn about the various ways Realm has changed since whatever version you were previously using.

Comment: so we use like [RLMNotificationToken stop];? but i still have error

Comment: If you're encountering a new problem, post a new question along with details about what the problem is you're encountering and what you've tried to fix it.

Comment: thanks i manage to use @property (strong, nonatomic) RLMNotificationToken *notificationToken;   and then call [_notificationToken stop]; is this correct. sorry for asking so many

Comment: Please post a new question rather than asking new questions in the comments.